# How to engage with Fedora 23 error message in dnf install error of dnspython?

Tags: fedora, cpio, dnf

I am not sure whether this constitutes a bug - so, I dare to try it here...
When attempting to install (with `dnf`) versions of the package `python-dns`, I get the following

> error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dnspython-1.12.0-py2.7.egg-info: cpio: rename

I run `4.3.4-300.fc23.x86_64` and have tried installing `python-dns-1.12.0-2.fc23.noarch` as well as `python-dns-1.12.0GIT465785f-1.fc23.noarch`.

The question is open, I am afraid: ideally I would learn how to solve the error; but I would also settle for advise where else I should post the question.

*added information as reaction to comments*

I used the command 
   "sudo dnf install python-dns"
to install the package.
python-dns-1.12.0GIT465785f-1.fc23.noarch came from the default fedora repository "Fedora 23 - x86_64".
python-dns-1.12.0-2.fc23.noarch came from http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=659336

Comment: where did you get these packages? What is the command you type before getting that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually get this when I've used pip to install/upgrade dnspython.  This can happen inadvertently when using pip to install some other python package that has dnspython as a dependency.  Try manually removing anything in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ related to dnspython and then try installing with dnf again.

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1307119 helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This usually means the file was corrupted in transit in some way. Normally, I'd suggest

```
sudo dnf clean packages
```

and then

```
sudo dnf install python-dns
```

again. It sounds like you've already tried this, including going direct to koji (Fedora's package build system) for a newer version. So, next, I'd run `rpm -K python-dns-1.12.0-2.fc23.noarch.rpm` (or whatever you have for the actual RPM file). This should return that the checksums and signatures are okay. Then:

1. If they're not okay, something is going wrong with your internet connection or you have a hardware problem causing corruption.
2. If they *are* okay, I'd suggest filing a bug. For what it's worth, though, I can't replicate this on my system.